# What does it mean when Coq expands a function as part of the goal?

Tags: coq

I was trying to solve the following theorem and got stuck at the last `simpl.`:

```
Lemma nonzeros_app : forall l1 l2 : natlist,
  nonzeros (l1 ++ l2) = (nonzeros l1) ++ (nonzeros l2).
Proof.
  intros l1 l2. induction l1 as [| n' l' IHl'].
  -simpl. reflexivity.
  -simpl. 
Qed.
```

at that point Coq changes the goal from:

```
1 subgoal (ID 170)

  n' : nat
  l', l2 : natlist
  IHl' : nonzeros (l' ++ l2) = nonzeros l' ++ nonzeros l2
  ============================
  nonzeros ((n' :: l') ++ l2) = nonzeros (n' :: l') ++ nonzeros l2
```

to:

```
1 subgoal (ID 185)

  n' : nat
  l', l2 : natlist
  IHl' : nonzeros (l' ++ l2) = nonzeros l' ++ nonzeros l2
  ============================
  match n' with
  | 0 => nonzeros (l' ++ l2)
  | S _ => n' :: nonzeros (l' ++ l2)
  end =
  match n' with
  | 0 => nonzeros l'
  | S _ => n' :: nonzeros l'
  end ++ nonzeros l2
```

which seems completely mysterious to me. What does it mean when Coq just copy pastes the definition of a function into my goal? What do I even do with this?

---

**Context of Question:**

Someone told me that the solution is:

```
Lemma nonzeros_app : forall l1 l2 : natlist,
  nonzeros (l1 ++ l2) = (nonzeros l1) ++ (nonzeros l2).
Proof.
  intros l1 l2. induction l1.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. { induction n.
             - ...
             - ... }
Qed.
```

which made me want to understand why they use induction on `n` since it feels it would never occur to me to use induction there. So I am asking, why? But I realized that before I could ask that why I didn't even understand the proof state before that since it just seemed to copy paste a function to a proof state (which makes no sense to me). So before I asked why use induction there I have to ask what does the proof state before that, maybe that would yield light into why induction on `n`.

Comment: crossposted: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-does-it-mean-when-Coq-expands-a-function-as-part-of-the-goal

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have defined `nonzeros` in the following way (or similar):

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.


Definition natlist := list nat.

Fixpoint nonzeros (l : natlist) :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | 0 :: xs => nonzeros xs
  | x :: xs => x :: nonzeros xs
  end.
```

So that `nonzeros` is recursive with structural decreasing on `l`.
Coq's `simpl` tactic employs a heuristic in which it unfolds definitions of fixpoints if they are applied to a term that has a constructor as the head symbol.
In your case, e.g., `nonzeros (n' :: l')`, the constant `nonzeros` is followed by a term formed by a constructor, `Cons` (=`::`). Coq performs a so-called "delta reduction", replacing the occurrence of `nonzero` with its definition. Since that definition is a `match`, you get a `match` as your new term. Further substitutions do simplify it a bit, but cannot eliminate the two cases: one for zero head and one for nonzero head.

Same happens to the occurrence `nonzeros ((n' :: l') ++ l2)`, which is first simplified to `nonzeros (n' :: (l' ++ l2))`, so that again, the head of the argument is `Cons`.

If you want to avoid exposing `match` expressions when simplifying, you can put the following directive after the definition of `nonzeros`:

```
Arguments nonzeros l : simpl nomatch.
```

This specifically tells `simpl` to avoid expanding a term if this will end up exposing a `match` at the location of the change.

As for the `induction` used by your friend here: it is applied to force a case split over `n'`, so that each case (`n' = 0`, `n' = S _`) can be handled separately. Indeed, induction is not needed here. A simple case split (`case n'`) will do the same.